# simple NSMutable array question

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmutablearray

umm So simple question here:

I have an instance of NSMutableArray declared in my header

```
NSMutableArray *day19;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *day19
```

implementation:

```
@synthesize day19;
```

In my viewDidLoad

```
self.day19 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

In the myMethod where I want to add objects to the array I:

```
NSObject *newObject = [[NSObject alloc] init];

[day19 addObject:newObject];
```

However... when i check the day19 array there is nothing in it.  If I conversely add the newObject to a tempArray within the myMethod scope and then set the day19 array to the tempArray, day19 has the objects.

Super basic I know just must be a confused morning or something...

thanks for any help

Comment: Hit up a Objective-C tutorial like this one: http://www.otierney.net/objective-c.html#nsarray

Comment: I have and all my tests in the local scope case work correctly... but if I try to add an object to a class instance variable... nothing sticks.

Comment: non-atomic should be nonatomic, and you have mismatched square brackets on the NSObject line.

Comment: The @property should also (nonatomic, copy)

Comment: ok i did my edits, just some typos in me posing the question.  but Im still having the problem.

Comment: Abizern: Declaring the property as `copy` will not help if it's meant to hold a mutable array, as `copy` returns an immutable array. It is a step toward the right solution, though: A property that is publicly immutable, but with mutation accessors (http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ModelObjects/Articles/moAccessorMethods.html) internally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In my viewDidLoad
>
> ```
> self.day19 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
> ```
>
> In the myMethod where I want to add objects to the array I:
>
> ```
> NSObject *newObject = [[NSObject alloc] init];
>
> [day19 addObject:newObject];
> ```
>
> However... when i check the day19 array there is nothing in it. If I conversely add the newObject to a tempArray within the myMethod scope and then set the day19 array to the tempArray, day19 has the objects.

Let me guess: You checked the array with code like this:

```
NSLog(@"day19 contains %lu objects", [day19 count]);
```

Remember that a message to `nil` does nothing and returns `nil`, `0`, or `0.0`. That's why the output said 0 objects: You don't have an array in the first place. The most probable reason for that is that `viewDidLoad` hasn't been called yet, so you have not yet created the mutable array.

It's also possible that you have an array (i.e., the view has been loaded) at the time you examine the array, but you didn't have an array yet (the view hadn't been loaded yet) at the time you tried to add to the array, so your `addObject:` message fell on deaf ears.

Consider creating the array earlier. You probably should be creating it in `init` or `initWithCoder:`.

A third possibility is that you examined the array before you ever added to it. Make sure you log or break at both points, so you know which one happened first.

Whatever the problem is, you also need to either assign the array to the instance variable, not the property, or autorelease the array before assigning it to the property. Otherwise, you're over-retaining the array, which means you will probably leak it later on. You probably need to review the [Memory Management Programming Guide for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/).

Comment: once again with the great answer.  I had actually figured it out previously but this rightly explains my error.  I was running the method to add objects to my arrays before actually alloc'in and init'n them in my ViewDidLoad method.  Simple copy paste error.  Thanks for the great answer.

Answer (score 1):

Is `day19` actually an instance variable? In the snippet, it's not clear when it's declared as an instance variable or just as a variable outside the scope of the class.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things:

Are you sure `viewDidLoad` is the right place to init your array? Confer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285513).

Also, at least from the code you've got posted, it looks like you're being sloppy with your retains. If your property is a retain type, you should not be writing:

```
self.myProperty = [[Something alloc] init]; // double retain here, bad
```

You should instead be writing something like:

```
self.myProperty = [[[Something alloc] init] autorelease]; // single, good
```

Also, with

```
NSObject *newObject = [[NSObject alloc] init];
[day19 addObject:newObject];
```

unless you have a

```
[newObject release];
```

down the pike, you've got a memory leak.